# How to derive the divergence leading to Kohn anomalies?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I'm trying to understand the mathematical derivation given in the book "A Quantum Approach to Condensed Matter Physics" on page 215 (see [1](http://books.google.at/books?id=hyx6BjEX4U8C&lpg=PR9&ots=YbZyz4NKQ9&dq=condensed%20matter%20physics%20%22condensed%20phase%22&lr&pg=PA215#v=onepage&q&f=false)), for explaining how the phonon-energy perturbed by phonon-electron interaction, namely

$$\hbar\omega_q^{(p)} = \hbar\omega_q - \sum\limits_k 2 | M_{kk'}|^2 \langle n_k \rangle (\varepsilon_{k'} - \varepsilon_{k})^{-1} $$

with $k' = k - q$ gives rise to the *Kohn anomaly* by making $\partial \hbar\omega_q^{(p)} / \partial q_x$ diverge when $q \sim 2k_F$.

The book explains that

> Let us suppose $q$ to be in the $x$-direction and of magnitude $2k_F$, and evaluate $\partial \hbar\omega_q^{(p)} / \partial q_x$.
>   If we neglect the variation of $M_{kk'}$ with $q$ the electron-phonon interaction contributes an amount
>   $$ 2 \sum\limits_k | M_{kk'}|^2 \langle n_k \rangle (\varepsilon_{k'} - \varepsilon_{k})^{-2} {\partial \varepsilon_{k-q} \over \partial q_x} .$$
>   On substituting for $\varepsilon_{k-q}$ one finds the summation to contain the factors $\langle n_k \rangle (k_x - k_F)^{-2}$. These cause a logarithmic divergence when the summation is performed [...]

What I don't grasp yet is the step of substituting for $\varepsilon_{k-q}$ (what exactly does one substitute with? $\varepsilon_k = \hbar^2 k^2 / 2m$?) and what the summation then looks like concretely to cause a logarithmic divergence.

Comment: There is either something weird in their derivation or I am stupid, but I will try to figure it out.

Comment: Ah I see. That's silly